# Polymer flush when calling fixture

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, web-component-tester, wct

Is it ok to put flush function in setup where the fixture called? I've tried it and it still work also better, because I don't need to flush in every single test. No example found on google doing that kind of things. Any suggestion?

```
setup(function(done) {
  flush(function() {
    var element = fixture('basic');
    done();
  });
});
```

And the test will be direct like this one.

```
test('instantiating the element works', function() {
    assert.equal(Polymer.dom(element.root).querySelector('paper-card').is, 'paper-card);
});
```

*The paper-card in test part is rendered inside dom-repeat.

Thanks all.